# Calling non-static methods using NetBeans GUI builder action listener

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans, static, actionlistener

I'm quite new to Java and programming, but I'm trying to learn by doing. To avoid too much hassle early-on I've used the NetBeans GUI builder to make a basic form with buttons and labels etc.

My problem is that when I call some methods inside the auto-generated Action Listener for a button, I get an error telling me how I cannot call a non-static method ( the dispose() method ) from a static context. While I understand the distinction between static and non-static in theory, I find myself lost when I'm sitting at the keyboard. I feel like I'm missing something important.

I need help getting un-stuck on this particular problem before I can move forward.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

well you cant just call `dispose()` as this is an instance method, you need to call dispose on the instance of your `JFrame` or `JDialog` or what-ever-window like this:

```
frame1.dispose():
```

Comment: Oh yes, I understand that. Turns out I had made another mistake with the dispose method which confused me. Does this mean though that there is no reason to want to call any static method in an action listener like this?

Comment: @user1578365 It simply means that you cannot call a non-static method without an instance of the object (created using `new` keyword) from a static context/method. See this for more clarification: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html